# Uploading a photo with Selenium WebDriver Java - css button

Tags: java, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have difficulties with uploading a file using a Selenium. I already read all the info in Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to work. I tried searching for the button or input using id/name/linkText/cssSelector/xPath, or even JavascriptExecutor. I then tried to click() it or sendKeys with a filepath, but nothing seems to work. When I click a button on the site I have a pop-up window, so wanted at least to make Selenium click it.
Here is the site source. Obviously I'm not getting something here.
What is wrong? How would you solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="image-uploader" class="btn primary">
     <form class="direct-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://some_address">
         <input type="hidden" name="key">
         <input type="hidden" value="AKIAJCYVQEAJNT7OGZAQ" name="AWSAccessKeyId">
         <input type="hidden" value="public-read" name="acl">
         <input type="hidden" name="policy">
         <input type="hidden" name="signature">
         <input type="hidden" value="201" name="success_action_status">
         <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" style="top: 25.5px; left: 20.5px;">
         </form>
    Add Image
</div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting...or is it just not uploading?

Comment: Just not uploading. Sometimes it looks like the button might have been hit but still no window is opened nor photo uploaded (using sendKeys)

Comment: Verify that your path is correct... (including escaping), and verify that your selector is correct.  If its not throwing an error, however, I imagine that your selector is write, because the other inputs are hidden.  If you can't get anything to work...you may have to try a workaround (such as the Robots class)

Comment: Thanks, i will try that! Quite sure the path is ok. Will read about Robots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to send keys to any node which has type=file. In your case, try using sendKeys to the below node -

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" style="top: 25.5px; left: 20.5px;">
```

Comment: Ok, It all works ok, I'm just dumb. Using Selenium IDE I can't find the button, but normal: 
driver.findElement(By.name("file")).sendKeys("C:\\path\\file.jpg");
works fine. I just misnamed the file in a way that was difficult to see. Thanks @praneel!